# How to get the entire web page source using Selenium WebDriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver in python, and I would like to retrieve in a variable the entire page source of the web page (something like the right click option that many web browsers provide to get the page source).

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your WebDriver object should have a [`page_source`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) attribute, so for Firefox it would look like

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.page_source
```

Comment: thats not view source code